# How to implement multistream networks with lateral connections in pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I need to work on a project for which I need two different branches for a neural network using PyTorch, fusing the output at a late stage. I would like to implement lateral connections so that the networks are able to share information, but I couldn't find any documentation about it. Is it possible to implement these types of connections in PyTorch in general? And if the two branches are a Convolution branch and a GNN/GCN branch?

Comment: using torch.concat

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question, but I'm working on a multichannel spatiotemporal CNN-GRU model. I initially built the model with Keras. But to answer your question I built it with pytorch too. I'm posting the both models here:

##### Model Architecture

[image]

##### Implementation on PyTorch

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class AttentionLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__()
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(input_dim, 1))

    def forward(self, x):
        e = torch.tanh(x @ self.W)
        a = F.softmax(e, dim=1)
        weighted_x = x * a
        return weighted_x

class MultiChannelCNN_GRU_Attention_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes, attention=True):
        super(MultiChannelCNN_GRU_Attention_Model, self).__init__()
        self.attention = attention
        self.conv_channels = 16

        self.conv_layers = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv1d(in_channels=input_shape[0], out_channels=self.conv_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=kernel_size//2),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(self.conv_channels),
                nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=1)
            )
            for kernel_size in [3, 5, 7]
        ])

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)

        self.attention_layer = AttentionLayer(self.conv_channels * len(self.conv_layers)) if attention else None

        self.gru_layer_1 = nn.GRU(input_size=self.conv_channels * len(self.conv_layers), hidden_size=32, num_layers=1, batch_first=True, bidirectional=False)
        self.gru_layer_2 = nn.GRU(input_size=32, hidden_size=16, num_layers=1, batch_first=True, bidirectional=False)

        self.gap_layer = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d(1)
        self.batch_norm_gap = nn.BatchNorm1d(16)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(16, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        conv_outputs = [conv(x) for conv in self.conv_layers]
        merged_features = torch.cat(conv_outputs, dim=1)
        dropped_features = self.dropout(merged_features)

        if self.attention_layer is not None:
            attention_output = self.attention_layer(dropped_features)
            dropped_features = self.dropout(attention_output)

        gru_output_1, _ = self.gru_layer_1(dropped_features)
        gru_output_2, _ = self.gru_layer_2(gru_output_1)

        reshaped_layer = gru_output_2.view(gru_output_2.size(0), -1)

        gap_output = self.gap_layer(reshaped_layer.permute(0, 2, 1)).squeeze()
        batch_norm_gap = self.batch_norm_gap(gap_output)
        output = self.output_layer(batch_norm_gap)

        return output

# Create an instance of the model
input_shape = (3, 128)  # Example input shape: (channels, sequence length)
num_classes = 10
model = MultiChannelCNN_GRU_Attention_Model(input_shape, num_classes, attention=True)

print(model)
```

Output:

```
MultiChannelCNN_GRU_Attention_Model(
  (conv_layers): ModuleList(
    (0): Sequential(
      (0): Conv1d(3, 16, kernel_size=(3,), stride=(1,), padding=(1,))
      (1): ReLU()
      (2): BatchNorm1d(16, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (3): MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
    (1): Sequential(
      (0): Conv1d(3, 16, kernel_size=(5,), stride=(1,), padding=(2,))
      (1): ReLU()
      (2): BatchNorm1d(16, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (3): MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
    (2): Sequential(
      (0): Conv1d(3, 16, kernel_size=(7,), stride=(1,), padding=(3,))
      (1): ReLU()
      (2): BatchNorm1d(16, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (3): MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
  )
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
  (attention_layer): AttentionLayer()
  (gru_layer_1): GRU(48, 32, batch_first=True)
  (gru_layer_2): GRU(32, 16, batch_first=True)
  (gap_layer): AdaptiveAvgPool1d(output_size=1)
  (batch_norm_gap): BatchNorm1d(16, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (output_layer): Linear(in_features=16, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

##### Implementation on Keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Layer, Flatten, Input, MaxPooling1D, Conv1D, BatchNormalization, Activation, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Reshape, GRU, concatenate
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras import backend as K

# multichannel_cnn_gru_attention_model
def multichannel_cnn_gru_attention_model(attention, input_shape, num_classes):
    class AttentionLayer(Layer):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def build(self, input_shape):
            self.W = self.add_weight(name="attention_weights", shape=(input_shape[-1], 1), trainable=True)
            super(AttentionLayer, self).build(input_shape)

        def call(self, x):
            e = K.tanh(K.dot(x, self.W))
            a = K.softmax(e, axis=1)
            weighted_x = x * a
            return weighted_x

    input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)
    channels = []

    for kernel_size in [3, 5, 7]:
        conv_layer = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01))(input_layer)
        activation_layer = Activation('relu')(conv_layer)
        batch_norm_layer = BatchNormalization()(activation_layer)
        pooling_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1)(batch_norm_layer)
        channels.append(pooling_layer)

    merged_features = concatenate(channels, axis=-1)
    dropout_layer = Dropout(0.5)(merged_features)

    # Apply the attention layer
    if attention:
        attention_layer = AttentionLayer()(dropout_layer)
        dropout_layer = Dropout(0.5)(attention_layer)

    gru_layer_1 = GRU(units=32, return_sequences=True)(dropout_layer)
    gru_layer_2 = GRU(units=16)(gru_layer_1)

    reshaped_layer = Reshape((-1, 16))(gru_layer_2)

    gap_layer = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(reshaped_layer)
    batch_norm_gap = BatchNormalization()(gap_layer)
    dropout_layer = Dropout(0.5)(batch_norm_gap)
    output_layer = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(dropout_layer)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer, name='multichannel_cnn_gru_attention_model')

    return model


input_shape = (3, 128)  # Example input shape: (channels, sequence length)
num_classes = 10 # output shape

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
# Create the model
model =  multichannel_cnn_gru_attention_model(attention=True, input_shape=input_shape, num_classes=num_classes)
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', keras.metrics.AUC(from_logits=True)])

print(model.summary())
```

Output:

```
Model: "multichannel_cnn_gru_attention_model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 3, 128)]             0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 conv1d (Conv1D)             (None, 3, 16)                6160      ['input_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_1 (Conv1D)           (None, 3, 16)                10256     ['input_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_2 (Conv1D)           (None, 3, 16)                14352     ['input_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 activation (Activation)     (None, 3, 16)                0         ['conv1d[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 activation_1 (Activation)   (None, 3, 16)                0         ['conv1d_1[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 activation_2 (Activation)   (None, 3, 16)                0         ['conv1d_2[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization (Batch  (None, 3, 16)                64        ['activation[0][0]']          
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_1 (Bat  (None, 3, 16)                64        ['activation_1[0][0]']        
 chNormalization)                                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_2 (Bat  (None, 3, 16)                64        ['activation_2[0][0]']        
 chNormalization)                                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1  (None, 2, 16)                0         ['batch_normalization[0][0]'] 
 D)                                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPoolin  (None, 2, 16)                0         ['batch_normalization_1[0][0]'
 g1D)                                                               ]                             
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPoolin  (None, 2, 16)                0         ['batch_normalization_2[0][0]'
 g1D)                                                               ]                             
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)   (None, 2, 48)                0         ['max_pooling1d[0][0]',       
                                                                     'max_pooling1d_1[0][0]',     
                                                                     'max_pooling1d_2[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 2, 48)                0         ['concatenate[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 attention_layer (Attention  (None, 2, 48)                48        ['dropout[0][0]']             
 Layer)                                                                                           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 2, 48)                0         ['attention_layer[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 gru (GRU)                   (None, 2, 32)                7872      ['dropout_1[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 gru_1 (GRU)                 (None, 16)                   2400      ['gru[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 1, 16)                0         ['gru_1[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling1d (  (None, 16)                   0         ['reshape[0][0]']             
 GlobalAveragePooling1D)                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_3 (Bat  (None, 16)                   64        ['global_average_pooling1d[0][
 chNormalization)                                                   0]']                          
                                                                                                  
 dropout_2 (Dropout)         (None, 16)                   0         ['batch_normalization_3[0][0]'
                                                                    ]                             
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)               (None, 10)                   170       ['dropout_2[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 41514 (162.16 KB)
Trainable params: 41386 (161.66 KB)
Non-trainable params: 128 (512.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

P.S. Anyway I find your question very interesting, let me know if you wanna discuss it further

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I've understood, this does not answer my question, because I would like to let the different branches communicate between them, as if there was, for example, a connection between conv1d and conv1d_1

Comment: okay, I will let you know if I find anything